# Undefined variable: $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, cakephp, e-notices

I'm getting `E_NOTICE` errors in a core CakePHP file when it tries to reference a never-set or unset session (`cake/libs/cake_session.php line 372`):

```
function read($name = null) {
    if (is_null($name)) {
        return $this->__returnSessionVars();
    }
    if (empty($name)) {
        return false;
    }
    $result = Set::classicExtract($_SESSION, $name);
}
```

I've done a search through my code (in the app/ directory) and I can't find references to `$_SESSION` or `session_destroy`.  Am I missing anything?

This error shows up when I try to run any unit tests.  Is this...normal?  I've cleared out the `cake/` directory and replaced it with another one (same version) just to make sure that I hadn't inadvertently modified anything in the core files, but I still get the same error.  I'm not sure if this is just a flaw in the framework or something else.

**EDIT**

Here are the results of the test run on the command line:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.11 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/program/app
---------------------------------------------------------------
CakePHP Test Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
Running app case models/owners_equity
E_NOTICE: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/program/cake/libs/cake_session.php on line 372
E_NOTICE: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/program/cake/libs/cake_session.php on line 372
ERROR->Unexpected PHP error [Undefined variable: _SESSION] severity [E_NOTICE] in [/var/www/program/cake/libs/cake_session.php line 372]
    in testGenerateOwnerWithdrawals
    in BalanceTestCase
    in /var/www/program/app/tests/cases/models/owners_equity.test.php

ERROR->Unexpected PHP error [Undefined variable: _SESSION] severity [E_NOTICE] in [/var/www/program/cake/libs/cake_session.php line 372]
    in testGenerateOwnerWithdrawals
    in BalanceTestCase
    in /var/www/program/app/tests/cases/models/owners_equity.test.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out there was some extra code in the AppModel that was messing things up:

in `beforeFind` and `afterFind`:

```
App::Import("Session");
$session = new CakeSession();
$sim_id = $session->read("Simulation.id");
```

I don't know *why*, but that was what the problem was.  Removing those lines fixed the issue I was having.

Answer (score 105):

You need make sure to start the session at the top of every PHP file where you want to use the `$_SESSION` superglobal.  Like this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['youritem'];
?>
```

You forgot the Session HELPER.

Check this link : [book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html)

Comment: I'm calling `Configure::write('Session.start', true);` in my core.php file.  Shouldn't Cake take care of it from there?

Comment: did u try session_start(); on the first line

Comment: session_name('CAKEPHP');
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility for this warning (and, most likely, problems with app behavior) is that the original author of the app relied on `session.auto_start` being on (defaults to off)

If you don't want to mess with the code and just need it to work, you can always change php configuration and restart php-fpm (if this is a web app):

**/etc/php.d/my-new-file.ini** :

```
session.auto_start = 1
```

(This is correct for CentOS 8, adjust for your OS/packaging)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody having this issue in **CakePHP 4.x**:

> Argument 1 passed to Cake\Http\Session::_overwrite() must be of the type array, null given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/rondeel/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Session.php on line 513

I was testing my authentication form and used a debug statement to post the form data. Turns out that that results in headers being sent before the session is started, which causes the `Cake\Http\Session::start()` method to fail:

```php
if (ini_get('session.use_cookies') && headers_sent()) {
    return false;
}
```

**Solution:** make sure not to echo or debug anything before the session is started.