# PHP Using Post method to transfer variable from a page to a third Page

Tags: php

I have a Login Page with the following Code;

```
                <p> Login  Name</p>
                <p>
           <input type="text" 
                  name="username" id="username">


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">


        </p>
            <p>
              <label for="password">Password<br />
                <br />
              </label>
              <input name="password" 
              type="password" id="password"></input>

            </p>

        <p>

          <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
          </p>
        <p><br />
```

and after capturing

i have also this code using the inputs

```
   require('config\db.php');
  session_start();
  // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
  if (isset($_POST['username'])){
  //$username1 = $_POST['username1'];;
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

I open a Page which has some options on logging in . I select one option on that page using radio buttons.
It opens a third page.

I want to display the User Name captured on the first page.

How can i do this?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Since you'll probably want the username again sometime try http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: don't blindly strip slashes from text. You're simply ASSUMING that magic_quotes is enabled, and you risk mangling a user's password if they really do have a backslash in it.

Comment: Thanks , i will latter upgrade to isql

Answer (score 0):

You have to store it somewhere.

A hidden input in the form in the second page is pretty reliable.

A session is a common choice, although subject to race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Store that user name in session
Then you can use it anywhere

To use session to should write **session_start();** which you have done.

Now just store your username in session.

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
```

echo you can print it by just

echo $_SESSION['username'];

for more information [go here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwi0p6WpvOXIAhWJHJQKHfJTDFw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fphp%2Fphp_sessions.asp&usg=AFQjCNFDMjE866tlGrmamZYRXat88TLNMg&sig2=pOaNOlLR6BGA1Bg72raLeg)

Comment: Thanks a lot , i have tried and get the error ;Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\sh\server\SymptomorDisease.php on line 62. I have even tried to add the <?php   ?>. Still same error. Please assist.

Comment: You need to start the session using session_start();  [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650090/undefined-variable-session)

Comment: Another related question . If instead of echoing i need to input it into a input box or label . How do i do it ? I tried <input name="Uname" type="text" id="Uname" value="=$_SESSION[&quot;username&quot;]" /> but it didnt work? This is on the third page

Comment: try this <input name="Uname" type="text" id="Uname"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']"  />